# Sharepoint 2010 and TMG configuration

Tags: authentication, central-administration, configuration

I have a SharePoint 2010 Portal that uses claims based authentication with NTLM. The portal was published to TMG with site name something like staff.portal.com
I have also installed certificates in SharePoint Server and updated bindings in IIS to use https and http. The AAM in SharePoint is also modified as below

> default zone = http://staff.portal.com
>
> Internet Zone = https://staff.portal.com

After configuring this I noticed few issues with SharePoint

Issue #1:

> If I access the portal externally (via TMG login screen) and go to site permissions and click on Check permissions or site collection administrators link I get a blank page. The reason is url of the page still uses http instead of https.

Issue #2:

> If I'm in the domain and try to open word or excel document it takes 2-4 minutes to load it. I suspect this is something to do with configuration in TMG. If I try to access the document externally via https the document opens instantly. To verify this I created another web application with Claims based with NTLM that is *not* published to TMG and if I access the documents it opens instantly.(within domain). So I'm pretty sure this is something to do with TMG.

Below is the current TMG configuration(partial). Could someone let me know if TMG is properly configured or if some additional steps are missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When publishing SharePoint sites to the Internet with SSL via ISA / TMG, you can deploy the SSL certificate to the TMG instead of the SharePoint web front-ends. With this configuration in mind, the TMG is responsible for the SSL encryption and communication between the TMG and the SharePoint front-ends is done in plain HTTP.

For this cenario, configuration goes like this:

Default zone:

- http://staff.portal.com

Internet zone:

- https://staff.portal.com (default AAM)
- http://staff-ssl.portal.com (alternate AAM)

For the Intranet zone:

1. extend the web application using the address http://staff-ssl.portal.com
2. go to the Alternate Access Mappings page and change the address of the default url for the Internet zone to https://staff.portal.com
3. add an alternate AAM to the Intranet zone that is http://staff-ssl.portal.com
4. add this host header to IIS on all web front-ends

On the TMG you need to publish the site with the SSL certificate to the Internet and configure TMG to send requests to the web front-ends using the address http://staff-ssl.portal.com.

TMG receives requests from the Internet for https://staff.portal.com and sends these to the internal url http://staff-ssl.portal.com.

Because the address http://staff-ssl.portal.com is an alternate url for the Internet zone, SharePoint knows that all links present in the returned pages / or redirects if any happen use the url known to the Internet which is https://staff.portal.com - the default for that zone.

In your **internal** DNS server you must setup **staff-ssl.portal.com** and **staff.portal.com** pointing to the IP of the SharePoint server or load balancer.

In your **external** DNS server you must setup **staff.portal.com** pointing to the IP of TMG.

Because you have the same host header for both http and http endpoints, you won't be able to access the site internaly through HTTPS. It's better to setup diferent host headers for either zone and not just diferent protocols (HTTP / HTTPS).

Comment: Hi Luis, do you think this will solve the slow opening of document?

Comment: Hi Kannabiran, I've deployed a fair number of SharePoint extranets with this configuration with great results.

Comment: Hi Luis, I want to use the same url either its within the domain or accessing externally. I believe the exten d web application is only if you want to use different url for internal and external access.

Comment: Hi Luis, to isolate the second issue mentioned in my post, we have removed the Sharepoint application from TMG and tried to access it within domain. We noticed the word/excel document pops up a login prompt and even if we enter correct username/pwd it pops up login window and if we cancel it opens the document and i'm able to save but the experience is not consistent as the word/excel client freezes...

Comment: If you want to use the same url for both internat and external use you don't have to extend, but if you want to use http for internal access and https (with SSL) for external access, then you need to extend.

Comment: Is the computer where you're accessing SharePoint connected to the domain and the user logged in with a domain account? Are you accessing SharePoint from the server itself or from a remote computer? Do you have multiple web front-ends or just one? Can you describe your architecture and network configurations?

Comment: We've tried this, but then InfoPath Form Services fails to work (i.e. InfoPath seems to use the FQDN of the server - the internal Windows Auth AAM, instead of the FBA site we setup). We believe we need SSL right-through into the SharePoint box.